# Obter todo o buffer do Console

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, console

Como eu posso obter todo o texto do Console (`System.Console`) para uma `String`, **sem redirecionar a saída do console para um processo**, por exemplo, quero obter o que está no Console através do próprio Console. Isso é possível? Se sim, como faço isso?

Comment: Mas de um outro console que não seja da sua aplicação? Sendo sua aplicação não seria apenas guardar as strings que são enviadas para a tela? Acho que não entendi, pode dar mais alguns detalhes?

Comment: Não. **A mesma aplicação deve ler o conteúdo de si mesma**, mostrando o que está na tela do mesmo jeito.

Comment: Então se é na mesma aplicação cairia no caso que comentei de guardar as strings, ou seja, se durante o decorrer da execução ela executa vários Console.WriteLine, bastaria adicionar em um buffer em alguma classe e quando precisar das informações do console acessar esse buffer. Qual o objetivo de acessar o log gerado no console? Varrer ele procurando alguma mensagem específica?

Comment: Queria salvar tudo que está no meu console para um arquivo de texto...

Answer (score 1):

Veja este exemplo daqui:

```
using System;
using System.IO;

namespace nsStreams
{
  public class Redirect
  {
    static public void Main ()
    {
        FileStream ostrm;
        StreamWriter writer;
        TextWriter oldOut = Console.Out;
        try
        {
            ostrm = new FileStream ("./Redirect.txt", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write);
            writer = new StreamWriter (ostrm);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine ("Cannot open Redirect.txt for writing");
            Console.WriteLine (e.Message);
            return;
        }
        Console.SetOut (writer);
        Console.WriteLine ("This is a line of text");
        Console.WriteLine ("Everything written to Console.Write() or");
        Console.WriteLine ("Console.WriteLine() will be written to a file");
        Console.SetOut (oldOut);
        writer.Close();
        ostrm.Close();
        Console.WriteLine ("Done");
      }
   }
}
```

Detalhes sobre o SetOut [aqui](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.setout%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Fonte: http://bit.ly/1WxW5JG

Comment: Mas ai está redirecionando o trecho para o arquivo, o quero é que vá para o arquivo/string e também para o Console, simultaneamente.